# Dropout in R: randomly remove elements and replace them with NA

Tags: r, machine-learning, dropout

I want to implement dropout i.e. randomly replace elements with NAs and return the vector/list back with NA values.

The wanted result is to reduce overfitting so there may be better convenience functions for this.

*Approach 1*

```
b<-rnorm(100); b[match(sample(b,10),b)] <- NA
```

where 10 values replaced with NA.

*Approach 2.* how to remove 90% of population? Not working, getting less than 90%:

```
b<-rnorm(99); b[match(sample(b,length(b)*0.9),b)] <- NA
```

that actually does not work because of possible matches i.e. selecting the same element.

**Is there any builtin or convenience function for dropout?**

Comment: Function `is.na<-` as in `is.na(b) <- sample(length(b), 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use function `is.na<-` to assign `NA` values to a vector.

```
set.seed(1)
b <- rnorm(100)
b[match(sample(b, 10), b)] <- NA

set.seed(1)
b2 <- rnorm(100)
is.na(b2) <- sample(length(b2), 10)

identical(b, b2)
#[1] TRUE
```

In order to implement the removal of 90% of population with `NA`'s, `sample` based on the length of the vector to be processed.

```
set.seed(1)
b <- rnorm(100)
is.na(b) <- sample(length(b), 0.9*length(b))
mean(is.na(b))
#[1] 0.9
```

Comment: How would you implement the removal of 90% of population with NAs?